# How can I parse an array list given in example?

Tags: java, arraylist, gson

I have an array and when i try to parse it gives me 
`com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` cannot be cast to `[Ljava.lang.Object;`

**Array Example :**

```
System.out.print(getObject().toString());
**[{msgid=2105630801, Sender=Z001}]**
```

I have already tried that **code snippet**

```
ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) getObject();
Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();

                                System.out.println("List elements : ");

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                    Object[] objects = (Object[]) iterator.next();
                                    for (Object object : objects) {
                                        System.out.print("@@@" + object);
                                    }
                                    System.out.print(iterator.next());
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below JSON is `JSONArray` with `JSONObject` were `JSONObject` implements `Map`

```
[{msgid=2105630801, Sender=Z001}]
```

So you can convert it into `List<Map<Object, Object>>`

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> list = (List<Map<Object, Object>>) getObject();
list.forEach(map->map.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k+"..."+v)));
```